# difference between exports.functionname and module.exports

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have seen two types of exports. Is there a difference between them? Is one style better than the other?

```
function start(route,handle) {
}
```

Style 1

```
exports.start = start;
```

style 2

```
module.exports = start
```

I suppose that they are the same as somewhere in there is a mapping between `exports` and `module.exports`. So is there a purpose to have these two styles?

```
exports = module.exports = {}
```